# Optimal iPad video settings?

Tags: video, codec, ipad, bitrate

I'm converting some video to put on an iPad, and recently MPEGStreamclip has been producing unsatisfactory results when I try and load it onto the device.  What are the optimal video settings for an iPad in terms of resolution, bitrate, codec, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**iPad playable media formats:**

Video files MP4, M4V, MOV file formats. H.264 video up to 720p, 30fps, main profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio; MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30fps, simple profile with AAC-LC audio up to 48kHz, 160Kbps, stereo audio.
Music and audio files in AAC, MP3, MP3 VBR, Audible, WAV, AIFF, Apple Lossless.

[Video/DVD to iPad Conversion Guide (Four ways)](http://www.dvdtoipad.com/)

Remember that the end result depends a lot on the quality of the video you started with.